# The total download is zero on my playstore account

Tags: android, google-account

I published my app on the play store, but despite having downloaded the application on six devices current installations are zero. 
How is it possible?

Comment: when you upoad app, it usually take 48 hours to update total number of downloads

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195975/applications-download-count-on-google-play-store/14196106

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about `Google Play Store` account and not related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on when you published your application, it will either update the download-scores over the next few hours (or so to speak "tomorrow") - or maybe you used the same Google account if these six devices are all yours, and it (maybe, not sure?) just does not count as 6 independent downloads but instead as one.

So option a) is to wait, and b) is to get someone else to download your app and wait again.

Answer (score 1):

The play store stats take between 24 - 72 hours to update. Give it a few days and you will see the number go up.

Also the numbers are grouped to buckets. So you'll see

```
0 - 10
10 - 50
50 - 100
100 - 500
500 - 1000
1000 - 5000
```

etc...

Comment: So there is no need to insert google analytics in my application ?

Comment: You don't have to, but you can if you want realtime statistics